# Curl/Json - retrieve value from curl json output

Tags: json, curl

How to retrieve one value from curl JSON output?

http://10.0.0.10/api/v4/projects/9/repository/commits/0d1c552f13141bcaf9280d38bcb8f44140b873f9/merge_requests

Returns

```
[{"id":40,"iid":23,"project_id":9,"title":"Feature 0"
```

I want to get only the value of ID.

I tried to pipe it to JQ but I get the error `Failed writing body`

```
http://10.0.0.10/api/v4/projects/9/repository/commits/0d1c552f13141bcaf9280d38bcb8f44140b873f9/merge_requests | jq -r '.id'
curl: (23) Failed writing body
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input is an array.

You need jq to get the first element first.

```sh
jq -r '.[0].id'
```